# Regex: Find four tabs, but then select the first { prior to the tabs

Tags: regex

I'm pretty close to what I need with this rubular:

http://rubular.com/r/tAzRj1H1z7

But, rather than selecting the whole block of which the lines are all indented with 4 tabs, I want to match the { that appears before the block.

Basically, this will allow me to search my codebase to find how many occurences of 4-tab blocks I have, rather than how many lines of 4-tab code.

/\t{4}.+/

```
.progressBar{
    .progressBarRow {
        .progressBarContainer {
            .progress {
                filter: none;
                -webkit-box-shadow: none;
                -moz-box-shadow: none;
                box-shadow: none;
                border: #b9b9b9 1px solid;
                height:40px;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can reverse the question: Find the first `{` that is followed by a line with four (or more) leading tabs. [This regex](http://rubular.com/r/sLnpeo4LSa) does the trick:

```
\{\s*\n\t{4,}
```

If for whatever reason you really only want to match the `{` itself, you can either put it in a group:

```
(\{)\s*\n\t{4,}
```

or use a look-ahead to make the whole match only `{`:

```
\{(?=\s*\n\t{4,})
```

Comment: Note that if you want to be more lenient regarding comments in the code, etc., you can use something more sophisticated like `\{[^{}]*\n\t{4,}`, which matches almost the whole block, but as one match, not one-per-line.

Answer (score 0):

```
\{(?=\s*\n\t{4}(?!\t))
```

Without **(?!\t)**, you're counting 5 or more tabs blocks also.